# how do the Lp spaces sit inside Teichmüller space?

Tags: lp-spaces, teichmueller-theory

I've heard it said that Teichmüller space gives a metric to the space of all metric spaces.

If this is so, where do the Lp spaces sit in the space of all metric spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you heard said is wrong. Instead, the Teichmüller space of an oriented surface $S$ of finite type gives a metric to the space of (isotopy classes of) complete, finite area hyperbolic metrics on $S$, meaning Riemannian metrics of constant curvature $-1$.

Comment: thank you, Dr Mosher!